# Line integral of a vector potential

Tags: electromagnetism

From the theory of electromagnetism, the line integral $\int {\bf A}\cdot{d{\bf s}}$ is independent of paths, that is, it is dependent only on the endpoints, as long as the loop formed by pair of different paths does not enclose a magnetic flux.

---

Why is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No magnetic flux means :

$$\int \vec B \cdot d \vec a=0$$

implies

$$\int (\nabla\times \vec A )\cdot d \vec a = 0$$

By Stoke theorem:

$$\oint \vec{A} \cdot{d\vec{l}}= 0$$

Which means $\vec A$ is path independent, as the area* is arbitrarily chosen, and a arbitrary loop integral is just sum of two arbitrary line integral (with overlapped starting and ending points).

---

*The integrals are over arbitrary area at where no flux, and the loop integral is over the boundary of the chosen area.

Comment: When I almost finished my answer, I found ACuriousMind has just answered it with answer almost same as mine; anyway, I think if readers are undergraduates taking E&M, my answer's notation will be more familiar to them, so I let this answer be finished .

Answer (score 2):

From a *slightly* different, though equivalent, view...

If the line integral of a vector field is path independent, the vector field is [conservative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field#Path_independence), i.e., the vector field is the [gradient of a scalar field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field#Definition).

Thus, if $\int \mathbf{A}\cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{s}$ is path independent, it is the case that $\mathbf{A} = \nabla \phi$.

Now, recall that the [curl of a divergence is identically zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Curl_of_the_gradient):

$$\nabla \times \nabla\phi = \mathbf{0}$$

But, the [magnetic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_potential#Magnetic_vector_potential) is $\mathbf{B} = \nabla \times \mathbf{A}$ and thus, in this case, $\mathbf{B} =0$

Answer (score 1):

It's a straightforward application of Stokes' theorem:

Given two paths $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ with the same starting and end points, let $\gamma := \gamma_1 - \gamma_2$ be the loop obtained by going from the starting point along $\gamma_1$ to the end point, and then in the reverse direction along $\gamma_2$. Let $S$ be a surface filling $\gamma$, i.e. such that its boundary is $\gamma$.

Then we have that
$$ \int_{\gamma_1} A - \int_{\gamma_2} A = \int_\gamma A = \int_{\partial S} A = \int_S \mathrm{d}A$$
and in vector notation $\mathrm{d}A$ is $\nabla\times A = B$. But $\int_S B$ is just the magnetic flux through $S$, so if there's no flux enclosed by $\gamma$, the two integrals along the paths are equal.